# Macro, increment the row number

Tags: vba, excel, row, increment

I am using an Excel macro to cut and paste some data and add it to the end of a list.
At the moment it is overwriting the last entry.

```
'macro                 
Range("A3:R93").Select                         
Selection.Copy                         
Range("T100000").Select                        
Selection.End(xlUp).Select  
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

This will take me to the last existing entry in column T.

I wish to paste my new data AFTER this so need to increment my current row by 1

Is there an easy way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to select a cell or cell range in order to copy or paste; in fact, it is better to avoid the practise.

```
Range("A3:R93").Copy _
  Destination:=Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

For values only:

```
With Range("A3:R93")
    Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With
```

This locates the last used cell in column T and then uses the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to shift the target of the paste 1 row down and 0 columns across.

If the source or destination area of the copy/paste may contain merged cells, you will need to [.UnMerge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210014%28v=office.12%29.aspx) them first. This is particularly important around the edges of the copy/paste areas where a merged cell may be half in and half out of the source or destination.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A3:R93")
rng.UnMerge
With Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    .UnMerge
    rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells
End With
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: @Bob - I've added some [Range.UnMerge method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210014%28v=office.12%29.aspx) code just in case.

Comment: That all worked a treat, both of them actually since I retried the first bit of code on a new spreadsheet

Comment: In regard to the first example, How would you do it so that it pastes it as values rather than as formulas?

Comment: Added value transfer method. This is the preferred method as it does not involve the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I now have, works fine, thank you Jeeped

```
Sub Report5()
'
' Create Report
'
'
Range("DA3:DC10000").Clear

If Range("aw4") Then
    With Range("BB3:BD9")
        Range("DA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With
End If

If Range("aw5") Then
    With Range("BB10:BD23")
        Range("DA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With
End If
```

etc for another 50 or so catagories